# TypeError: Не удается вызвать метод "getRange" объекта null

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Суть скрипта в отправке сообщения на почту, адрес которой берется из таблицы Google, вы выполнении выдает ошибку: `TypeError: Не удается вызвать метод "getRange" объекта null`.

Почему методу getRange передается объект null?

```
function sendMails() {
  // число адресатов 
  var rowsAmount = 3;
  // Здесь надо указать тему писем 
  var messageSubject = "Пресс-релиз"; 
  // Создаем переменную для активного листа
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Выделяем диапазон данных и получаем из него данные
  var dataRange = currentSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowsAmount, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  // Обходим поочередно ряды в таблице
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    // Из первого столбца берем адрес
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    // А из второго имя получателя
    var messageText = row[1] + ", " + "высылаем Вам пресс-релиз"; 
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, messageSubject, messageText);
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, это значит, что _SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()_ вернул `null`

Comment: Не так. У объекта `null` вызывается `.getRange()`. Выполните `console.log(currentSheet);` - посмотрите, что там будет. Предполагаю, что там будет `null`.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, `Logger.log()` ? И @grundy написал так как надо.

Comment: @iandryax5, вы не сказали, в каком контексте выполняется скрипт. Это [Standalone или Bound](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

вернет лист только тогда, когда вы вызовете функцию из документа, сайдбара, либо из созданного меню в документе (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Если вы хотите протестировать вашу функцию из редактора кода, вам необходимо открыть документ по id или по ссылке

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
```

и затем выбрать лист

```
var currentSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var currentSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего проблема в контексте.

Либо скрипт выполняется вне Таблицы, т.е. это standalone скрипт, либо он привязан к Документу.

Необходимо переписать

```
var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

на что-то вроде такого

```
var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name);
```

Код из топика полностью рабочий. Пример [TypeError: Не удается вызвать метод “getRange” объекта null [634069] #ruSO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14N2GcGJcUyMDgT9iq3TD_GhsQSzA4AJ87iAKPWtHQ-U/copy) Меню - Проба - sendMails